# R: parsing unequal-length elements of a list-type variable within a dataframe into separate (flattened) variables

Tags: r

I have a dataframe object that contains 825812 obs and 3 variables, the first of which (AF) is a list. The length of the unlisted list variable is 839390 because some obs have more than one AF value assigned.

```
length(TRAIN_vcfAF$AF) #825812
length(unlist(TRAIN_vcfAF$AF)) #839390
```

I would like to do three things:
1. pull the first element of the list for each obs into a new variable, 'AF1'; pull the second element (if present) for each obs into new variable, 'AF2', and so on (if any obs has >2 AF values)
2. create 'AF0' which will be the minimum of AF1, AF2, AFn....
3. create a column that provides the number (count) of unique AF values in the dataframe for each obs.

NOTE: The dataframe has informative rownames (chromosomal positions), that I would like to preserve in the output df.

Below is the str() call on the dataframe and a partial print of the dataframe.

```
str(TRAIN_vcfAF)

'data.frame':   825812 obs. of  3 variables:
  $ AF  :List of 825812
..$ : num 8.04e-05
..$ : num 8.04e-05
..$ : num 0.00113
..$ : num 0.000161
..$ : num 0.000321
..$ : num 8.04e-05
..$ : num 8.04e-05
...
.. [list output truncated]
..- attr(*, "class")= chr "AsIs"
$ drop: logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
$ X : num  8.04e-05 8.04e-05 1.13e-03 1.61e-04 3.21e-04 ...

# partial print:
TRAIN_vcfAF[1:6,]

                            AF  drop       AF0
chr1.100111836.56777 8.035e-05 FALSE 8.035e-05
chr1.100111850.56778 8.035e-05 FALSE 8.035e-05
chr1.100127842.56781  0.001126 FALSE 1.126e-03 
chr1.100133162.56783 0.0001607 FALSE 1.607e-04 
chr1.100133187.56785 0.0003214 FALSE 3.214e-04
chr1.100133328.56788 8.035e-05 FALSE 8.035e-05
```

Answer (score 1):

The last two are very simple:

```
TRAIN_vcfAF$AF0 = sapply(TRAIN_vcfAF$AF, min)
TRAIN_vcfAF$unique = sapply(TRAIN_vcfAF$AF, function(o) length(unique(o)))
```

For the first one, there may be tools for that, but just with basic manipulation you can simply do something like:

```
n = seq_len(max(sapply(TRAIN_vcfAF$AF, length)))
AF = t(sapply(TRAIN_vcfAF$AF, function(o) o[n]))
colnames(AF) = paste0("AF", n)
TRAIN_vcfAF = cbind(TRAIN_vcfAF, AF)
```